# Using Matlab to write a column vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a list of population for 10 years and I want to enter it as a column vector into matlab but  I only know how to write a row vector

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html

Comment: `[10; 20; 30]` defines a column vector. Note `;` as row separator

Comment: Consider taking a basic MATLAB tutorial such as "[Get Started with MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html)" or [MATLAB-OnRamp](https://www.mathworks.com/learn/tutorials/matlab-onramp.html)